# Using fresh compressed cake yeast in bread machine

Tags: bread, yeast, rising

While using  compressed cake yeast in bread machine it rises well for the first rise but on the second rise it does not rise well and I get a deep concave surface , I typically add 3x the dry yeast recommended in the recipe as I had read that fresh yeast is 3x less concentrated then dry ones.

Answer (score 2):

After reading some papers on this I experimented by adding the yeast 5 minutes before the kneading ends. This gave an acceptable loaf without any collapsing but did not even get a big convex bulge. The rationale behind this is that fresh yeast is already active and the 20 minutes of kneading already uses up its potential partially adding it later saves 15 minutes of activity for the other stages. So yes it is possible and cost effective too as dry yeast is costly compared to the fresh yeast even after weight conversion.